# Use returned dash datatable in another callback

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I have a form in Dash that takes in value and returns a filtered datatable based on that value:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=[100,4]), columns=set('ABCD'))
print(df)

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

controls = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [
                dbc.Label("Select group"),
                dbc.Input(id="group", type="number", value=3),
            ]
        ),
        html.Div(id='my_output'),
        html.Div(id='s_rows')
    ],
    body=True,
)

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(controls, md=4),
            ],
            align="center",
        ),
    ],
    fluid=True,
)


@app.callback(
    Output('my_output', 'children'),
    [
        Input("group", "value"),
    ],
)
def filtered_data(group):

    data = df[df['D'] == group]

    return dash_table.DataTable(
                    style_cell={
                        'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                        'height': 'auto',
                    },
                    id='table',
                    columns=[
                        {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True} for i in data.columns
                    ],
                    data=data.to_dict('records'),
                    editable=True,
                    filter_action="native",
                    sort_action="native",
                    sort_mode="multi",
                    row_selectable="multi",
                    selected_columns=[],
                    selected_rows=[],
                    page_action="native",
                    page_current=0
                )

@app.callback(
    Output('s_rows', 'children'),
    [
        Input('table', 'selected_rows'),
    ]
)
def get_checked(selected_rows):
    return selected_rows

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8000)
```

As you can see in the first callback, the function, returns the filtered data table with an option for the user to select rows.

I want to be able to pass in the selected rows into another callback, but Dash isn't recognizing the ID I've set for the returned datatable, giving me the error:

```
ID not found in layout
Attempting to connect a callback Input item to component:
  "table"
but no components with that id exist in the layout.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `selected_rows` is not defined as soon as the app runs, it will give you an error that no components with that id exist in the layout, since that component hasn't been defined yet. If you also look more closely at the error, at the end of it, it also says to `suppress this exception by setting suppress_callback_exceptions=True` if `you are assigning callbacks to components that are generated by other callbacks (and therefore not in the initial layout)`.

So all you have to change in your app is add `suppress_callback_exceptions` in the defining of your app:

```
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP], suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
```